# Uploading the file on azure blob container doesn't work

Tags: c#, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to upload a file on an azure blob, the purpose of this application is to log all the exceptions to the azure blob, for this purpose I created a .net core console application and called this application using web API but it runs perfectly fine from the local system, but when I upload/deploy it on azure app service it doesn't work at all, your help would be highly appreciated. thank you :-)

```
public static async Task UploadBlob(string Information)
    {
        var connectionString = "ConnectionString Goes here";
        string containerName = "logs";
        var serviceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
        var containerClient = serviceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
        var path = @"c:\temp";
        var fileName = "filename.txt";
        var localFile = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
        await File.WriteAllTextAsync(localFile, Information);
        var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient($"{DateTime.Now.Year}/{DateTime.Now.Month}/{DateTime.Now.Day}/{fileName}");
        //var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(sal/fileName);
        Console.WriteLine("Uploading to Blob storage");
        using FileStream uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(localFile);
        await blobClient.UploadAsync(uploadFileStream, true);
        uploadFileStream.Close();
    }
```

Comment: _”it doesn’t work”_  - this is not enough information for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: For one thing, though, on an app service `c:\temp` won’t exist. You could use `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()` but using a file stream from a local file in an app service seems like an odd thing to do, why not just create a `memoryStream` from `Information`?